# How can I share common functionality in a multitude of web sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my server I have twenty asp.net sites. How do I make them share one general functions class without having to duplicate that general functions class twenty times?

My sites are all .net 2 and using c#

Can I do this with a service?

Comment: The sites can either reference the same assembly, or create a webservice for better deployment of the dependency.

Comment: you mean like make it a web service or package it as a dll ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compile your common classes and functions into a library and include that library as a reference in each of the twenty sites.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new, empty Class Library Project.

Put all the code you want to share in one (or several) classes in that project.

Set a reference to that project in your ASP.net websites.

Answer (score 0):

if all the 'sites' are purely asp.net as you mention and are not likely to change from that platform, then create a common dll and reference that on each. if you find that later on you have to cater for mixed 'languages' (php, ruby, python, java, etc, etc), then go for a webservice (or more likely a RESTApi) approach.

Each approach has it's advantages and disadvantages, so based on your fuller requirements, only you will know where the line is drawn.